# marketing cloud - is adding a new business unit free?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

My client has ent 2.0 with 1 parent and 4 children BUs.

Is adding a new BU free or it has a cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional Business Units - if not already covered by your contract - need to be puchased at an additional cost. To know for sure, you need to check your contract to see wether you the fifth BU is already contracted.

In an enterprise account 5 BUs are part of the standard package: [How to Select the Right
Marketing Cloud Edition](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf)